# Navbar active scroll on footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

My one page layout is working perfectly except for one issue. The navbar links when clicked changes color according to where the user goes to or scrolls.

[image]

The problem is that when I click on the "Contact Us" link, the navbar scrolls to that position but the navbar link doesn't change color as pictured above. It works for every other section just not for the bottom because the area isn't big enough.

```js
window.onload=function(){
        // Cache selectors
        var lastId,
                topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
                topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
                // All list items
                menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
                // Anchors corresponding to menu items
                scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
                    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
                    if (item.length) { return item; }
                });

        // Bind click handler to menu items
        // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
        menuItems.click(function(e){
            var href = $(this).attr("href"),
                    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
                    scrollTop: offsetTop
            }, 300);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        // Bind to scroll
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            // Get container scroll position
            var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

            // Get id of current scroll item
            var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
                    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
                        return this;
            });

        // Get the id of the current element
        cur = cur[cur.length-1];
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

        if (lastId !== id) {
                lastId = id;
            // Set/remove active class
            menuItems
                .parent().removeClass("active")
                .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
        }                   
        });
        }//]]>
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf')
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-ExtraLight.otf')
}

body    {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    margin: 0px;
}


#header {
    top: 0px;
}

.signsize   {
    width: 140px; 
    height: 90px;
    }

.movesimg   {
    float: right;
    }

.packing    {
    float: left;
    }

h1  {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin:0;
    }

h2  {
    margin: 0;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    }

h3  {
    color: #3d3d3d;
    }

h4  {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin:0;
    }

h5  {
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin: 0;
    }

h6  {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #929292;
    margin:0;
    }

#descriptionl   {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #929292;
    margin:0;
    }

#descriptionr   {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #929292;
    text-align: right;
    margin:0;
    }


#movessec   {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    border-bottom: solid thin #d8d8d8;
    }   


#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
        background: white;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo   {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#top-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;

}

#top-menu li {
        float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#more   {
    padding-left: 50px;
    }

#moreR  {
    padding-right: 50px;
    }

#more li {
        float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: #4690d4 solid thin;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#moreR li {
        float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: #4690d4 solid thin;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#top-menu a {
        display: inline;
        width: 6em;
        text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
        -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
        transition: .5s all ease-out;
        color: #545454;
        text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
        color: #575757;
}

#top-menu li.active a {     
        color: white;
    position: relative;
    background: #4690d4;
}

#home {
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 150px;
        height: 800px;
    background-image: url(img/movingboxes.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

#services   {
    height: 1600px;
    }

#servicesleft   {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    }

#servicesmain   {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 76%;
    }

#servicesright  {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    }


#moving {
        height: 800px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-right: 12%;
    background-image: url('img/cardboardbright.jpg');
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

#quote {
    height: 800px;
    background: grey;
}

#contact {
    height: 325px;
}

#contactleft    {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    background: white;
}

#contactmain    {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 76%;
    background: white;
}

#contactright   {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div id="header">

        <div id="navbar">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="logosmall.png">
            </div>
                <ul id="top-menu">
                    <li class="active">
                            <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#moving">Moving Tips</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#quote">Get A Quote</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="home">
            Content Here.
        </div>

        <div id="services">
        <div id="servicesleft"></div>
        <div id="servicesmain">
            <div id="movessec">
                Content Here.   
            </div>

            <div id="movessec">
                Content Here.   
            </div>

            <div id="movessec">
                Content Here.   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="servicesright"></div>
        </div>  


        <div id="moving">Content here.</div>    

        <div id="quote">Quote form goes here.</div>

        <div id="contact">
            <div id="contactleft">Content Here</div>
                <div id="contactmain">Content Here</div>
            <div id="contactright">Content Here</div>
        </div>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the change of the `active` class to the click, here i have commented out the change that happens on scroll, moved it to the click event, and also added a line to get the id:

```js
window.onload=function(){
        // Cache selectors
        var lastId,
                topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
                topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
                // All list items
                menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
                // Anchors corresponding to menu items
                scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
                    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
                    if (item.length) { return item; }
                });

        // Bind click handler to menu items
        // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
        menuItems.click(function(e){
            var href = $(this).attr("href"),
                    id = href.split('#')[1],
                    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
                    scrollTop: offsetTop
            }, 300);
            e.preventDefault();

            menuItems.parent().removeClass("active").end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
        });

        // Bind to scroll
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            // Get container scroll position
            var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

            // Get id of current scroll item
            var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
                    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
                        return this;
            });

        // Get the id of the current element
        cur = cur[cur.length-1];
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

        if (lastId !== id) {
                lastId = id;
            // Set/remove active class
            //menuItems
            //    .parent().removeClass("active")
            //    .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
        }                   
        });
        }//]]>
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf')
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    src: url('fonts/Montserrat-ExtraLight.otf')
}

body    {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    margin: 0px;
}


#header {
    top: 0px;
}

.signsize   {
    width: 140px; 
    height: 90px;
    }

.movesimg   {
    float: right;
    }

.packing    {
    float: left;
    }

h1  {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin:0;
    }

h2  {
    margin: 0;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    }

h3  {
    color: #3d3d3d;
    }

h4  {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin:0;
    }

h5  {
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    margin: 0;
    }

h6  {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #929292;
    margin:0;
    }

#descriptionl   {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #929292;
    margin:0;
    }

#descriptionr   {
    font-family: 'MontserratSlim';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #929292;
    text-align: right;
    margin:0;
    }


#movessec   {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    border-bottom: solid thin #d8d8d8;
    }   


#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
        background: white;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#logo   {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#top-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;

}

#top-menu li {
        float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#more   {
    padding-left: 50px;
    }

#moreR  {
    padding-right: 50px;
    }

#more li {
        float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: #4690d4 solid thin;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#moreR li {
        float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    outline: #4690d4 solid thin;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#top-menu a {
        display: inline;
        width: 6em;
        text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
        -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
        -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
        transition: .5s all ease-out;
        color: #545454;
        text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#top-menu a:hover {
        color: #575757;
}

#top-menu li.active a {     
        color: white;
    position: relative;
    background: #4690d4;
}

#home {
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 150px;
        height: 800px;
    background-image: url(img/movingboxes.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

#services   {
    height: 1600px;
    }

#servicesleft   {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    }

#servicesmain   {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 76%;
    }

#servicesright  {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    }


#moving {
        height: 800px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-right: 12%;
    background-image: url('img/cardboardbright.jpg');
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

#quote {
    height: 800px;
    background: grey;
}

#contact {
    height: 325px;
}

#contactleft    {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    background: white;
}

#contactmain    {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 76%;
    background: white;
}

#contactright   {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12%;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div id="header">

        <div id="navbar">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="logosmall.png">
            </div>
                <ul id="top-menu">
                    <li class="active">
                            <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#moving">Moving Tips</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#quote">Get A Quote</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="home">
            Content Here.
        </div>

        <div id="services">
        <div id="servicesleft"></div>
        <div id="servicesmain">
            <div id="movessec">
                Content Here.   
            </div>

            <div id="movessec">
                Content Here.   
            </div>

            <div id="movessec">
                Content Here.   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="servicesright"></div>
        </div>  


        <div id="moving">Content here.</div>    

        <div id="quote">Quote form goes here.</div>

        <div id="contact">
            <div id="contactleft">Content Here</div>
                <div id="contactmain">Content Here</div>
            <div id="contactright">Content Here</div>
        </div>


    </body>
```

Comment: the click works and manages to highlight the contact link but it fails to highlight the links when I scroll the page. I'd rather it do both if possible.

Answer (score 0):

By setting a `min-height` to `100vh` you can make sure it is always at least the height of the user's screen.

Comment: that would work but I want the the section to be a specified height.

Comment: Well then unfortunately I can't help you there. However if you make only the _bottom_ section 100vh then there will always be space to move the top of the viewport below the top of any section